# Could not find path?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, ide

When I try to run Debug, gradle console shows this error:

```
Could not read path 'C:\proj_x\mobile\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\8\prux\celx\gmi\pinx\persistence\database'.
```

> C:\proj_ponto\mobile\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\8\prux\celx\gmi\pinx\percistence\database

But when I click Make Project (hammer icon), shows BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 54s;

I've already tried running clean project, but it gives this error message:

```
 Unable to delete directory: C:\proj_x\mobile\app\build\intermediates\transforms\instantRunSlicer\debug\8\prux\celx\gmi\pinx\persistence
```

Note: Ignore directories names hehe

Comment: delete this directory manually

Comment: The problem is that I need this directory

Answer (score 0):

Just delete Build directories from app and project directory, then click "Make Project"